# Overhead of NSNotifications

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nsnotification

I recently started using `NSNotification`s:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName: selector: object:]; ....
```

I find it to be an awesome concept for communicating between view controllers. It almost seems a little too easy to use `NSNotification`s for all the communications in the app.

In the event that I use `NSNotification`s for most of the work in my app, what do you think would be the overhead for too many of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to recall reading that NSNotification is pretty overhead consuming, so using a lot of them probably wouldn't be the best idea.  Instead, I'd look into adopting `delegate` protocols.  You can easily create your own to tell your files what to do and when.

[This site](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/delegates/how-to-create-a-delegate) gives an example fairly similar to the one I used to learn how to create delegates and might be worth looking into.  I used to use NSNotifications all the time until I learned about delegates and have since switched all my notifications over to delegate methods instead

Comment: Delegates are great, no doubt, but they aren't a replacement for notifications. Also the overhead won't be noticeable if the App doesn't send out 30+ per run loop cycle.

Comment: Very true, you've gotta be using a lot of `postNotification` calls to really notice any difference.  I suppose I'm just a bit guilty of having a preference towards delegates as opposed to notifications

Comment: That was awesome. Thanks for the LINK!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297829/funny-nslogs-understanding-nsnotifications-help

Answer (score 7):

One of things you need to remember about `NSNotification`s are that they are a blocking mechanism. So while the object posting the notification need not know who is receiving it, if there are too many receivers, it will have to process all of them before the `postNotification` call can return. That is something that you will have to take into consideration.

As such, like @slev said, delegates are a better approach. Use notifications only when you can't use the delegate approach.

Comment: Deepak - any chance of chat ?

Comment: This is the main risk of NSNotifications. Say you're notifying a neighbor object that a network request has completed, and firing it off to process that request. The NSNotification happens on the main thread, and unless you do something about it, the function that gets called will do its work on the main thread too. If it's a long-running process, that'll block the UI (things won't scroll or animate, it'll just look frozen) until that process is done. Even worse if you've got a stack of observers to call, the UI blocks until they're *all* done.

Comment: That said, I use them and I like them. You just have to know their limitations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297829/funny-nslogs-understanding-nsnotifications-help

Comment: If blocking the main thread is an issue, you could use NSNotificationCenter's addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: method to add the observer. This gives you flexibility to choose the thread in which to process the notification. Also, a selector is invoked when a notification is posted, you can always write code within the selector such that it does not block the main thread.

Considering NSDistributedNotificationCenter is also an option.