# NSNotification does not reach all Observers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, nsnotifications

I use `NSNotification` for a particular set of events. I have three views such that I have an "ADD" button on view 1 and clicking that makes me navigate from view 1 to view 2 to view 3 and again back to view 1.

*1->2->3->1*

I use `NSNotification`s to push a view controller if the ADD button on view 1 is clicked, and I update the other views respectively, based on the notification posted by View 1.

When the notification is sent from view 1, only view 2 receives it. View 3 does not.

How is this possible? The code for observers is EXACTLY the same on view 2 and view 3.

This is the code for adding observers in view 2 and view 3:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(didPressAdd:) 
                                             name:@"DidAddNotification" 
                                           object:nil];
```

I also remove them in the `dealloc()` function properly.

Comment: You probably added the observer in viewDidLoad or similar and the view has not loaded yet. So it has not yet registered for the notification and cannot receive it.

Comment: I tried it in viewDidLoad (Did not Work). I also tried in viewWillAppear (Does not work either ) :|

Comment: See my answer below, comment box too small.

Comment: @Legolas, I've expanded the [`earlier sample`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/DogDayAfternoon.zip) to suit this case. I couldn't reproduce this.

Comment: But how is it different from [`this`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6297829/view-controllers-sometimes-do-not-receive-an-nsnotification)?

Comment: @Deepak: Could you try this. Post a new notification from DogTableViewcontroller on clicking ADD. Add the other two views as observers with their usual navigation for clicking ADD in view 1. And NSLog them.

Comment: @Deepak: It is the same. But I have understood that the problem lies in the fact that view 3 does not listen to the notification.  I have  made the changes in your code. http://www.cl.ly/3q0o2w0l003O1y122D2c  (Added notification in ADD BUTTON code) and (added observers for other views )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigating back to 1 using navigation controller will remove 2 and 3. So in dealloc, add a log saying that the particular controller has stopped listening. You shall see that the listener is being deallocated after which it won't listen to notifications. Updated the [`sample`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/DogDayAfternoon1.zip) to send a notification on return.

Comment: Deepak, I had posted this in the previous comment. But I am posting it again.. http://www.cl.ly/3q0o2w0l003O1y122D2c is what I am trying to do...

Comment: Like I said, they are being deallocated before you send the notification so they are not listening. What surprises me is that there is no exception being triggered when the notification is being sent as that is what the documentation says. I am able to see them being deallocated before the notification is being sent.

Comment: And if you want this chain to work i.e. 1->2->3, then you will need to retain the controllers that you're pushing onto the navigation controller otherwise they will be deallocated as soon as they are popped. So create them if they are nil and retain them then push them onto the navigation controller.

Comment: so, now I have more information :P so.. i added NSLog to all dealloc functions... // None of them are being called...

Comment: You can check the updated [`sample`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/DogDayAfternoon-1.zip) that retains the controllers.

Comment: Sure. I will check it out right away. In this sample http://www.cl.ly/0P30391a3J2n1y0h0n1x   , why does it not NSLog when observers receive notification ?

Comment: Deepak, the code you sent me .. THAT HAS THE SAME PRBLEM. Could you come on chat

Comment: ok. But the latest code I sent does it properly i.e. both 2 and 3 receive the notifications. You can recheck.

Comment: Join the room for Legolas and Deepak :)

Comment: Could you tell me where you read about initWithMode  ? And also regarding ViewControllerModeAdd and ViewControllerModeGeneral ?

Comment: It's not a `UIKit` feature. It is something that you need to create.

Comment: Roger. Could you send me in the right direction ? Any links for creating custom initialization methods ?

Comment: @Deepak, Could you help me with the initialization part ?

Comment: Sample [`here`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/Dogs.zip). Probably not a completely functional copy but will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:` are called after you send the notification. Set it up in `initWithNibName:bundle:` instead (if you use xib files) or some other `init` method if you don't (`initWithCoder:` for example), assuming you have inited the controller somewhere. If you have not inited the controller, you can't really listen for notifications inside it either.

Comment: So I pasted the code in the initWithStyle method of view 3 along with a NSLog. It gets called only when I navigate to view 3 from view 2. From what you are saying - " If you have not inited the controller, you can't really listen for notifications inside it either." How would I initiate view three when I click add ?