# Monitoring NSNotifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I noticed in a comment on this post [Overhead of NSNotifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295999/overhead-of-nsnotifications), user JustSid says

> the overhead won't be noticeable if the App doesn't send out 30+ per run loop cycle

I'd like to write a little helper class that keeps track of how many NSNotifications have been sent on the current run loop cycle and alert me if it's above a certain pre-configurable number. I know I can register for all notifications (pass nil to name and object), but how do I track what run loop cycle they've been sent from?

Comment: IMHO this approach seems suspect. I have seen no evidence that using NSNotificationCenter is any higher overhead than sending messages directly between objects. Any performance issues would be specific to the handling of notifications (vs the sending). If you have a large number of objects observing a notification and/or doing thread blocking tasks that would obviously have an impact on app performance. That's where I would focus time and energy. @JustSid's comment is arbitrary and speculative.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy enough to have a category on NSNotificationCenter that increments some internal integer when a notification observer is added (and consequently decrements it when it is removed), but you have to ask yourself: How much is too much?

If you consider it to be some arbitrary integer (say, 30 for example's sake), then what happens when you test it on a device that has more memory and processor constraints than the one you have now?  What happens if you test it on a device that can easily handle 30 observers and notifications floating around (it would be a complete waste)?  While it would be possible to code general rules, it would be impossible to gauge the impact notifications have on application response time in every case.

The other possibility would be having a background process query the notification stack (or somehow just gauge it internally like above) when the amount of observers brings certain system functions to a crawl.  Of course, ignoring the fact that this is way too much work, you'd be designing a sub-system which probably utilizes as much memory and steals as much away from performance as you tried to remedy with it in the first place!

TL;DR There are so many other patterns and structures you could be using instead of notifications, so why are you the one catering to NSNotification's needs?

Comment: This is something I only plan on running while debugging, and I'm more worried about the amount of notifications being sent rather than the amount of observers in my case. I only have a handful of observers. I have a class that watches the main thread and if it doesn't respond for a configurable period of time it NSLogs "Main thread is unresponsive". I was thinking of a tool similar to that. The number of notifications is pretty arbitrary but it would be nice to know if I'm sending 20 notifications per run loop and I make a change and am all of a sudden sending 500 notifications per run loop.

Comment: Then just use that class.  It seems general enough to deal with blocking notifications as well.  Or, if you're up to it, re-write NSNotificationCenter.  It really shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: And my answer is that A) You told me you have a tool that can track thread blocking, and B) that such a tool would be too unwieldy to be useful.  You'd not only need to keep track of the main thread, but you'd need to filter for *only* NSNotification's methods blocking the loop.  At least, it's too unwieldy as you have it laid out (debugging tools are usually separate from the app itself so they don't interfere with the app's execution and report false data).  Reword or reask a question about that for a "better" answer.

Comment: //Track How Many Are Being Sent Per Run Loop Cycle// EXACTLY!  You'd need to *Track* the run loop and *filter* the number of notifications sent!  Without an exposed RunLoop interface or object (NSRunLoop is OS X only), how do you expect to do this?  That's precisely why I've been telling you it's far too much work.  Trust me, if getting the run loop's calls were easy, there'd be a million answer about ways to do it.

Comment: And do you expect the run loop to just hand this over to you?  The run loop doesn't care about what's executed, the run loop only cares about running code in a timely manner.  Not only that, but there is no exposed API for accessing the run loop on iOS!  Again, trust me, if this were easy, there would be far more answers about it.

Comment: Well, that's a much more helpful answer. I've updated my question to try and make it a little clearer. Thanks for the help.